# Flask: return render_template from outer def instead of @app.route's def

Tags: python, flask

+NOTE: This is my very first question on StackOverflow, feedback is more than welcome.

I am working on a website with a lot of pages and I want to show some results from a query with a template when users use the search bar, but if users go to my page with the navbar I want to render another template.

```
   @app.route("/python", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
   def python():
       language = 'python'
       search(language)
       return render_template("python/python.html")

   def search (language):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            query = request.form['search_input']
            print(query)
            return render_template('results_render.html',
            language = language, results = query)
```

After a bit of testing I summarized the behavior:
  - 1. I don't know whether my results_render.html gets returned/rendered.
  - 2. I know my python/python.html page gets rendered, but I don't know
  whether this is 
    overriding my results_render.html's render or not.

My expected behavior would be:
  - 1. If a user goes to myhost/python the
      `return render_template("python/python.html")` should run. 
  - 2. If a user searches for something in myhost/python the `def search(languages):` should `return render_template('results_render.html',
language = language, results = query)` whilst overriding
 `return render_template("python/python.html")`

OPTIONAL: If necessary routing the user to myhost/language/results (with language being a var) would be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the value returned by `search`. You can use `request.method` to decide if that's needed, so it becomes:

```
@app.route("/python", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def python():
    language = 'python'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return search(language)

    return render_template("python/python.html")
```

As per your example, or even better:

```
@app.route("/python", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def python():
    language = 'python'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = request.form['search_input']
        results = search(language, query)
        return render_template(
            'results_render.html',
            language = language,
            results = results
        )

    return render_template("python/python.html")

def search(language, query):
    results = do_something_to_get_results(language, query)
    return results
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot